# Electrons attraction (in opposite magnets)

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics

It's often said that there are aligned "domains" inside magnets, and electrons inside these domains are aligned as well - which gives to a magnet it's macroscopic effect.

That made me realize all of a sudden that m***i***croscopically, if we'll look at opposite and touching poles of 2 magnets - electrons inside them must be constantly attracting each other (while still being attracted the strongest to their nuclei).

Now... in QED it must mean that electrons on both sides are creating a field of "attractive" virtual photons in the direction of another magnet, and the other side is just happen to "attractively" receive them (which one can call an "exchange"). But, while I'm making up this assumption - I'm actually asking for some links, or titles with detailed quantum explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual photons are just Fourier components of, in this case, the magnetic dipole field. They do not propagate and are not exchanged.

Btw it is not "often said" but a fully validated model that there are magnetic domains. Physics is not based on hearsay.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to undervalue magnetic domains: I just used it as a starting point to highlight my interest, which is QED.